# Tomcat 8.5.13 Cookie Issue

Tags: tomcat8

We were using tomcat version:8.0.33 and tried migrating to 8.5.13

We used cookies in the application. But after deploying the application in the mentioned version, experienced the before error while reading back the cookie,

> 2017-04-11 16:13:04 ERROR error:176 - Exception occurred in class
>   com.TestController the exception details are:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [34] was
>   present in the Cookie value at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.validateCookieValue(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:182)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.generateHeader(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:115)

and later found the fix for the problem:

```
    // Previous code: 
    final Cookie cookies = new Cookie(key, value);
        //Fix code: 
final Cookie cookies = new Cookie(key, URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
```

We have to encode the values in the cookies.

Comment: try adding more information about your problem

Comment: To begin with: the code that is triggering this problem

Comment: Updated the question with the fix. Encoding the cookie value resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

ASCII character 34 (%x22) is the double quote (").

Quoting the relevant part of RFC 6265:

```
cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                      ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                      ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                      ; and backslash
token             = <token, defined in [RFC2616], Section 2.2>
```

As you can see from the above, %x22 is not a valid cookie-octet. Tomcat will allow you to add the optional start and end double quote but a double quote anywhere else will trigger the error you are seeing.